# Attempting to use moment.js for date validation. Error message won't display

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, momentjs

I am attempting to make a simple registration form in Javascript and I'm trying to use moment.js for date validation. So far my username validation and password validation all work however I can't seem to get my date validation to work. I saw other threads on here asking about date validation and most people suggested to use moment.js for it. That is where I am stuck. I am just trying to get the form to check if the date is in the valid MM-DD-YYYY format. Any help would be appreciated.

I also seem to get a Depreication warning and I'm not sure what to do about that.

```js
function validateform() {
  var username = document.getElementById('username');
  var password = document.getElementById('password');
  var firstname = document.getElementById('firstname');
  var lastname = document.getElementById('lastname');
  var dob = document.getElementById('dob');
  var email = document.getElementById('email');
  var phone = document.getElementById('phone');

  if(username.value.length < 8){
    alert("Username must be at least 8 characters");
    form.username.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (password.value.length < 8) {
    alert("Password must be at least 8 characters");
    form.password.focus();
    return false;
  }
}

function vailddatecheck(dateString) {
  var dateforvailidation = dateString.value;
  var isVaild = moment(dateforvailidation, 'MM-DD-YYYY' , true).isVaild();
  if (isVaild) {
    return true;
    }
    else {
      alert("Date must be in MM-DD-YYYY format");
      form.dob.focus();
      return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Totally Legit Registration Page</title>
    <link href="Mod4style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form class="submit.html" method="post" class="simpleForm" onsubmit="return validateform()">
      <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="User Name">
      <p class="error"></p>
      <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
      <p class="error"></p>
      <input type="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="First Name">
      <p class="error"></p>
      <input type="lastname" id="lastname" placeholder="Last Name">
      <p class="error"></p>
      <input type="dob" id="dob" placeholder="Date of Birth"  onchange="vailddatecheck(this)">
      <p class="error"></p>
      <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
      <p class="error"></p>
      <input type="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Phone Number">
      <p class="error"></p>
      <button type="Submit">Submit</button>
      <button type="Reset">Reset</button>
    </form>
    <script <script src="formvalidation.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment@2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      moment("dateforvailidation").format();
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: You have some typos, maybe thats why it isn't working?

Comment: Where are the typos?

Comment: Moments validation function is called `isValid`, not `isVaild`.

Comment: simple enough. I've fixed the typo. However, I still can't get it to validate the date

Answer (score 0):

As @putvande mentioned in comment you need to call isValid not isVaild.

Not sure why you want to call validate function on change of date input, you can call it as other validations on submit in your validateform function.
or you can wrap this code in your vailddatecheck function and call it in validateform.

```
let isVaild = moment(dob.value, 'MM-DD-YYYY' , true).isValid()
  if (!isVaild) 
  {
    alert("Date must be in MM-DD-YYYY format");
      form.dob.focus();
      return false;
   }
```

Comment: I have wrapped that into my validdatecheck function but I'm unclear on how to call it in my validateform. How would I do that?

Answer (score -1):

Per [moment's documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/):

> Moment's parser is very forgiving, and this can lead to
>   undesired/unexpected behavior.
>
> For example, the following behavior can be observed:
>
> ```
> moment('2016 is a date', 'YYYY-MM-DD').isValid() //true, 2016 was matched
> ```

You may want to try [HTML input's `date` type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date), however it will always display date in browser locale and will work only [in browsers that support it](https://caniuse.com/#search=input-date).